# Display taxonomy color in custom post archive

Tags: custom-post-types, color-picker

I'm still new to programming and therefore a bit lost...

I've created a taxonomy "status" for custom posts.
I've added a ACF field named "bpn_statuscolor" which gets its value "color" from a ACF color picker.

I have a archive page of custom posts with the taxonomy display under the post title.
I would like to color the background of those taxonomies according to their assigned color.

How do I proceed? I did a lot of research ending up with a code like this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'color' );
if( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
    echo 'div class="sp-pcp-post-meta" <div style="background-color:' . get_field( 'bpn_statuscolor', 'color' . $term->term_id ) . '"> </div>';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have no clue where to add the code as until now I'm only working with CSS (where php code is not working obviously).

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You would use the code on your (archive) template file, which you use to display the custom posts. On the template the code would be placed within [the Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/).

For example you could have a custom post type specific archive file for this (more on [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)).

```
// archive-$posttype.php
while ( have_posts() ) :
  the_post();
  $statuses = wpse_410403_status_terms( get_the_ID() );
  ?>
    <div class="entry">
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <div class="sp-pcp-post-meta">
        <?php
          if ( $statuses ) {
            foreach ($statuses as $status) {
              echo wpse_410403_status_html($status);
            }
          }
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php
endwhile;
```

I would recommend using helper functions, placed in your theme's `functions.php` file, for retrieving the terms and their meta data to keep your template file cleaner and making it easier to maintain your codebase.

In my example above I've used a helper function to retrieve the post's custom taxonomy terms. This is to force the result to be always an `array` as `get_the_terms()` returns `false` or `WP_Error` in some cases.

```
function wpse_410403_status_terms( int $post_id ) : array {
  $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'status' );
  return $terms && is_array($terms) ? $terms : [];
}
```

For retrieving the color value you can have another function. This way you can protect your site from the situation when ACF is not active and it's `get_field()` function is not available. If that happens you can fallback to WP's native `get_term_meta()` function to retrieve the stored color value from the term meta (*which ACF also does after jumping through few hoops*).

```
function wpse_410403_status_color( WP_Term $term ) : string {
  return function_exists('get_field')
    ? get_field( 'bpn_statuscolor', $term )
    : get_term_meta( 'bpn_statuscolor', $term->term_id, true ); // check that the meta key is correct and matches the way ACF stores the data
}
```

Then a third function, for rendering the status terms with background color, for reusability.

```
function wpse_410403_status_html( WP_Term $term ) : string {
  return sprintf(
    '<span class="status" style="background-color: %s;">%s</span>',
    sanitize_hex_color(
      wpse_410403_status_color( $term )
    ),
    esc_html( $term->name )
  );
}
```

And of course, you can always wrap all three functions into a single function for even cleaner template usage.

```
function wpse_410403_statuses( int $post_id ) : string {
  $statuses = wpse_410403_status_terms( $post_id );
  return $statuses
   ? implode( '', array_map( 'wpse_410403_status_html', $statuses ) )
   : '';
}
```

I.e.

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
  the_post();
  ?>
    <div class="entry">
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <div class="sp-pcp-post-meta">
        <?php echo wpse_410403_statuses( get_the_ID() ); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php
endwhile;
```